# Playwright equivalent to cy.scrollTo('bottom')

Tags: playwright

I am looking for the equivalent to cypress scrollTo bottom so that I can load all of the lazy loaded content prior to taking a screenshot.

Comment: There is no builtin API to that would keep scrolling page in a loop, you can do something like  `await page.evaluate(() => window.scrollBy(0, 1000));`. If the element is in the DOM you can scroll to it with `locator.scrollIntoViewIfNeeded`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.